# Hibernate: Select entities where collection contains all of the specified valus

Tags: java, hibernate, collections

I need assistance with a tricky hibernate query problem. I have the following entities:

```
public class Book {
   private String bookId;
   private String author;
   private String isbn;
   private Set<Tag> tags;
   // getters, setters etc.
}
```

and

```
public class Tag  {
   private String tagId;
   private String tagName;
  // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

There is a many-to-many association between the two that is represented by a join table books_tags_mn with the columns book_id and tag_id.

What I like to do is the following: I want to create a hibernate query/criteria query that returns all book that have **all** of a certain set of tags. What does work is to select all books that have **any** of a set of tags.

I've been messing around with the criteria API but did not truly understand it. So what I am trying to do (in pseudo HQL)

```
from Book book where book.tags containsAll(:tags)
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciated, so thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the following query:

```
select book from Book book
where :numberOfTags = (select count(tag.id) from Book book2
                       inner join book2.tags tag
                       where book2.id = book.id
                       and tag in (:tags))
```

where `numberOfTags` is the number of tags in the set of tags that must be matched.

Comment: In case the collection can contain duplicates (not on IDs) you might want to add count(distinct)

Comment: How to express this as a Hibernate Criteria instead of HQL?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to create two custom functions or restriction as :

```
 collect(book.tags) -> returns list of tags associated with the book

 containsAll(bookTagsList, tags) --> validates and returns true if all 
                                     tags elements are present in bookTagsList 
                                     returned by the first function "collect"
```

Once functions are defined and registered, you would be able to run HQL/criteria query like:

```
 from Book book where containsAll(collect(book.tags), :tags)
```

or

```
session.createCriteria(Book.class).add(
           Restrictions.add(collect("tags").containsAll(tags))
        ).list();
```

Please Note: This is just a sample pseudo code to share the idea.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer from JB Nizet is good but will not work if your collection can contain duplicates (might be a valid reason for that, probably not with the tag example though).

Lets say the collection for some books can contain duplicate tags with the same name "MyTag". Then a search for the Tags "MyTag", "YourTag" could return books that have 2 "MyTag" tags but no "YourTag" tag.

```
select b from Book b where :numberOfTags = (select count(distinct tag.tagName) from Book b2 inner join b2.tags tag where b2.id = b.id and tag.tagName IN (:tagNames))
```

As I said nothing wrong with the accepted answer but if you need to support duplicates in the collection then you need to add count(distinct tag.name)