# HQL one to many query

Tags: sql, grails, hql, grails-orm

I have a CarModel and CarModelColor Domain
Relationship is CarModel hasMany CarModelColor

```
CarModel{
  String name
   static hasMany = [carModelColors: CarModelColor]
}

CarModelColor{
  String color
}
```

Now if you pass 2 color say `red and black` we need all those models which hai both color atleast. Please note that user can pass n number of color to that function and result need atleast that n colors .

Answer (score 0):

Can be done as follow using in query

**HQL**

```
select model from CarModel as model 
join model.carModelColors as modelColors
where modelColors.color in ?
```

**Criteria**

```
 CarModel.withCriteria {
    carModelColors {
       "in"("color", colorList)
    }
}
```

Comment: no , If you use 'in' it will give those with have only one color. i need those have both color

Comment: @Ashu see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784960/hibernate-select-entities-where-collection-contains-all-of-the-specified-valus

Answer (score 0):

Rather a simple query

```
CarModel{
  String name
   static hasMany = [carModelColors: CarModelColor]
}

CarModelColor{
  String color
}
```

Query is

```
String query="""
select new map(cm.id  as id, cm.name as name, cmc.color as color) from CarModel cm left join carModelColors cmc where cmc.color in (:colorList)
""
Map wp=[:]
wp.colorList=['red','black']
def results = CarModel.executeQuery(query,wp,[readOnly:true])
```

But now you will end up with as many iterations of carModel as their colours so if both found then two.

So you could add a `group by cm.id`

The trick above is the left join and obviously `in (:list)`

You could drop the select new map and get the raw object if you prefer by doing :

```
   String query="""
   from CarModel cm where cmc.carModelColors.color in (:colorList)
    ""
    Map wp=[:]
    wp.colorList=['red','black']
    def results = CarModel.executeQuery(query,wp,[readOnly:true])
```

The moment you start adding left joins which means nulls or all records rather than definitive set which is a join and join also does not return the hasMany where as left join returns all records.

But if you added a left join

```
String query="""
select new map(cm as carModel) from CarModel cm left join carModelColors cmc where cmc.color in (:colorList)
""
Map wp=[:]
wp.colorList=['red','black']
def results = CarModel.executeQuery(query,wp,[readOnly:true])
```

You can then get the real object from results.carModel

It is all gone off tracks but it shows you all the ways of doing the same way it depends on what is going on with that domain object sometimes I do from since in the domain object are lots of forward walking goodies to query away from.

Remember a map is flat and contains typically a flat map of elements and is lightweight compared to objects passed around (in the sql world)