# how to find that the list contains all elements from the another list?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Within my spring boot project I have a defined Chat and User entity that are related by many to many

**Chat.java**

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "chat_user",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "chat_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
```

**User.java**

```
@ManyToMany
@JsonBackReference
@JoinTable(name = "chat_user",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "chat_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<Chat> chats = new HashSet<Chat>();

public Set<Chat> getChats() {
    return chats;
}

public void setChats(Set<Chat> chats) {
    this.chats = chats;
}
```

how to write a method inside CrudRepository so that I get a Chat list that contains **all** users from the list of users

So far I have a written method that returns a chat list that contains **any** of the users in the user list

```
public interface ChatRepo extends CrudRepository<Chat, Long> {
List<Chat> findAllByUsers(User user);
List<Chat> findDistinctByUsersIn(Set<User> users);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem here? Get all chats, iterate over them and check whether their set of users (not a list btw) contains the set of passed users. One of the methods you could use is the `containsAll()` method. One way to optimize that would be to do that in a query. There's probably some HQL function for that (which I don't remember) but a quick query came up with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784960/hibernate-select-entities-where-collection-contains-all-of-the-specified-valus

Comment: i just tried it this way but when applying the method containsAll () always returns false as a response. So I want to check if there is a way to get that response with the repository method

Comment: What I understood is that you have a list of users and you want to fetch All chats of each user as a single list? Am I right ?

Comment: All chats which contains all Users from received list of users as a single list.

Comment: Does your User class implement `equals/hashCode` properly? Otherwise, `containsAll` won't work.

Comment: Thanks Malte, your answer worked for me, I added @Override equals/hashCode methods and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implementing equals/hashCode like Malte Hartwig suggest is solution

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {

    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof User)) {
        return false;
    }
    User user = (User) o;
    return id == user.id &&
            Objects.equals(firstName, user.firstName) &&
            Objects.equals(lastName, user.lastName) &&
            Objects.equals(userName, user.userName) &&
            Objects.equals(password, user.password);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, firstName, lastName, userName, password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward solution to this(from what I see). What you can do is
Create a method in your ChatRepo like this

```
public interface ChatRepository extends CrudRepository<Chat, Long> {

  @Query("select c from Chat c WHERE :user in elements(c.users)")
  List<Chat> getChatsWithUsers(@Param("user") User user);
}
```

This will get you the result of all the Chats which this particular user is part of.
And then you can do this for all the Users in your set and then do a intersection of the results.
For this to work you need to put `@ElementCollection` in your Chat class

```
..........
@ElementCollection
  private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
```

But I agree this is not a ideal solution because if the list is too big, then it results in multiple database calls

Answer (score 0):

```
   @ManyToMany
 @JoinTable(name = "chat_user",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "chat_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = 
 "id"))
  private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

  I think this is maybe wrong. Because one chat id cannot point out many user. 
  So you can use simple jointable to user entity
```