# Search by value in a Collection of String

Tags: hibernate, jpql

I have to find all the films in which the actors I pass in the list have worked together, the problem is that it returns all the films in which each actor in the list has worked, even individually

IN clause don't seems to work, where am i wrong?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new it.package.Project.payload.response.FilmResponse(" +
        "fs.filmStaffId.film.filmId, " +
        "fs.filmStaffId.film.title, " +
        "fs.filmStaffId.film.description, " +
        "fs.filmStaffId.film.releaseYear, " +
        "fs.filmStaffId.film.languageId.languageName) " +
        "FROM FilmStaff fs " +
        "LEFT JOIN Staff s " +
        "ON fs.filmStaffId.staff = s.staffId " +
        "WHERE fs.filmStaffId.staff.lastName IN :lastNames AND fs.filmStaffId.role.roleName = 'ACTOR'")
List<FilmResponse> getByActors(@Param("lastNames") Collection lastNames);
```

This is my query

Comment: PLease provie the entity definition and sample dataa

Answer (score 0):

Indeed your query returns the films where at least one actor was involved. If your are sure that there is no duplication in the relation film-actor (an actor is not mentionned twice in a film) you can make a subrequest counting these relations and testing if the number is equal to the name list count. Check this as an example : [Hibernate: Select entities where collection contains all of the specified valus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784960/hibernate-select-entities-where-collection-contains-all-of-the-specified-valus).